# MinMax TicTacToe Java

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minmax

For the past few days I have been trying to implement the minmax algorithm in a tictactoe using Java. My attempt so far has some success, however it is not unbeatable and makes mistakes a lot of the time with placing its tokens. I was hoping for some advice on how to fix my code:[image]

In the picture blue is the player, and red is the AI, blue goes first. In this situation red should place their token in the middle square 
[image]

Here instead of blocking the player red places their token in the top right.

Something is causing the AI to be really aggressive, and always go for a line without considering what the other player is doing but I cannot figure out what is causing this, because in some cases the computer will block the player.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.prism.BasicStroke;

import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class Main extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    int[][] board = new int[3][3];
    boolean turn = true;
    int movex = 0;
    int currMoves=0;
    int movey=0;
    int score;
    int[][] tempboard = new int[3][3];
    int[][] minMax = new int[3][3];
    ArrayList<Integer> posMovess = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> posMovesx = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> posMovesy = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().init();
    }

    public void init(){
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseListener(this);

    }
    int max =0;
    public int recttt(int[][] tempboard, int XO){
        int score = 0;

        posMovess.clear();
        posMovesx.clear();
        posMovesy.clear();
        max= 0;
        if(tempboard[0][0] == 1 && tempboard[0][1]==1 && tempboard[0][2]==1 ||
                tempboard[1][0] == 1 && tempboard[1][1]==1 && tempboard[1][2]==1 ||
                tempboard[2][0] == 1 && tempboard[2][1]==1 && tempboard[2][2]==1 ||
                tempboard[0][0] == 1 && tempboard[1][0]==1 && tempboard[2][0]==1 ||
                tempboard[0][1] == 1 && tempboard[1][1]==1 && tempboard[2][1]==1 ||
                tempboard[0][2] == 1 && tempboard[1][2]==1 && tempboard[2][2]==1 ||
                tempboard[0][0] == 1 && tempboard[1][1]==1 && tempboard[2][2]==1 ||
                tempboard[0][2] == 1 && tempboard[1][1]==1 && tempboard[2][0]==1 ){
            return -1; //if player wins return negative
        }else if(tempboard[0][0] == 2 && tempboard[0][1]==2 && tempboard[0][2]==2 ||
                tempboard[1][0] == 2 && tempboard[1][1]==2 && tempboard[1][2]==2 ||
                tempboard[2][0] == 2 && tempboard[2][1]==2 && tempboard[2][2]==2 ||
                tempboard[0][0] == 2 && tempboard[1][0]==2 && tempboard[2][0]==2 ||
                tempboard[0][1] == 2 && tempboard[1][1]==2 && tempboard[2][1]==2 ||
                tempboard[0][2] == 2 && tempboard[1][2]==2 && tempboard[2][2]==2 ||
                tempboard[0][0] == 2 && tempboard[1][1]==2 && tempboard[2][2]==2 ||
                tempboard[0][2] == 2 && tempboard[1][1]==2 && tempboard[2][0]==2){
            return 1; // if computer wins return positive
        }
        int count = 0;
        for(int x = 0;x<3;x++){
            for(int y = 0;y<3;y++){
                if(tempboard[x][y] == 0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(count==0){
            return 0; //if tie return neutral
        }

        for(int x =0;x<3;x++){
            for(int y = 0;y<3;y++){

                if(tempboard[x][y] == 0){

                    if(XO % 2 == 0){
                        tempboard[x][y] = 1;
                        XO+= 1;
                        posMovess.add(recttt(tempboard,XO));
                        XO-=1;
                        posMovesx.add(x);
                        posMovesy.add(y);
                        tempboard[x][y] =0;
                        for(int i = 0;i<posMovess.size();i++){
                            if(posMovess.get(i) < posMovess.get(max)){
                                //calculate min for players turn
                                max = i;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        tempboard[x][y] = 2;
                        XO+=1;
                        posMovess.add(recttt(tempboard,XO));
                        XO-=1;
                        posMovesx.add(x);
                        posMovesy.add(y);
                        tempboard[x][y] =0;
                        for(int i = 0;i<posMovess.size();i++){
                            if(posMovess.get(i) >posMovess.get(max)){
                                //calculate max if computers turn
                                max = i;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return posMovess.get(max);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("");
        int best = -2;
        int temp = 0;
        currMoves++;
        board[e.getX()/200][e.getY()/200] = 1;
        turn = false;
        repaint();
        for(int x = 0;x < 3;x++){
            for(int y = 0;y< 3;y++){
                //call minmax algorithm for each available space
                if(board[x][y] == 0){
                    board[x][y] = 2;
                    temp = recttt(board,1);
                    System.out.println(temp);
                    board[x][y] = 0;
                    if(temp > best){
                        best = temp;
                        movex = x;
                        movey = y;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        best = 0;
        currMoves++;
        board[movex][movey] = 2;
        turn = true;
        repaint();
        if(board[0][0] == 1 && board[0][1]==1 && board[0][2]==1 ||
                board[1][0] == 1 && board[1][1]==1 && board[1][2]==1 ||
                board[2][0] == 1 && board[2][1]==1 && board[2][2]==1 ||
                board[0][0] == 1 && board[1][0]==1 && board[2][0]==1 ||
                board[0][1] == 1 && board[1][1]==1 && board[2][1]==1 ||
                board[0][2] == 1 && board[1][2]==1 && board[2][2]==1 ||
                board[0][0] == 1 && board[1][1]==1 && board[2][2]==1 ||
                board[0][2] == 1 && board[1][1]==1 && board[2][0]==1 ){
            System.out.println("Blue Wins");
        }else if(board[0][0] == 2 && board[0][1]==2 && board[0][2]==2 ||
                board[1][0] == 2 && board[1][1]==2 && board[1][2]==2 ||
                board[2][0] == 2 && board[2][1]==2 && board[2][2]==2 ||
                board[0][0] == 2 && board[1][0]==2 && board[2][0]==2 ||
                board[0][1] == 2 && board[1][1]==2 && board[2][1]==2 ||
                board[0][2] == 2 && board[1][2]==2 && board[2][2]==2 ||
                board[0][0] == 2 && board[1][1]==2 && board[2][2]==2 ||
                board[0][2] == 2 && board[1][1]==2 && board[2][0]==2){
            System.out.println("RedWins");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        for(int i = 0;i< 3;i++){
            g2.drawLine(200*i, 0, 200*i, 600);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i< 3;i++){
            g2.drawLine(0, 200*i, 600, 200*i);
        }
        for(int x = 0;x<3;x++){
            for(int y = 0;y<3;y++){
                if(board[x][y] == 1){
                    g2.setColor(Color.blue);
                    g2.drawOval(x*200+50, y*200+50, 100, 100);
                }
                if(board[x][y] == 2){
                    g2.setColor(Color.red);
                    g2.drawOval(x*200+50, y*200+50, 100, 100);
                }
            }   
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add example inputs and outputs for the current code to allow those reviewing to more quickly see what the behavior of it is?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added some pictures to help clarify the issue.

Comment: I think that your posMoves? lists and max should all be declared in the function they are executing in. You're currently setting up possible moves, then removing them during subsequent recursive calls. declare and create them within the function instead of resetting them.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you very much.